Prevent Duplicate Rule Firing for the Data integration user
We implemented Duplicate Rules but even if we have Alert type, they stop Bulk API from insertion of records.
How can we still have Duplicate Rules enabled for usual business users but disable it for the Bulk API job?

Since we plan to launch Bulk API under Data Integration user, we should just add a condition to the duplication rule that user profile name is not equal to data integration user.
We need to have custom ProfileName formula on User record because of the known issue
